# No qualifying bean repository with r2dbc postgres

Tags: spring, postgresql, r2dbc

I recently try to using r2dbc with postgres "0.8.8.RELEASE" (pg r2dbc maven dependecy) and spring boot "2.5.2"

I declared following properties in my application.yml:

```
   spring:   jpa:
    properties:
      hibernate:
        dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQL82Dialect
    hibernate:
      ddl-auto: create
    show-sql: false
    database-platform: org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect   r2dbc:
    url: r2dbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/postgres
    username: postgres
    password: postgres
    pool:
      enabled: true
      initial-size: 00
      max-size: 500
      max-idle-time: 30m
      validation-query: SELECT 1   sql:
    init:
      schema-locations: classpath:/schema.sql
      mode: always
```

Bellow my Application.java:

```
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = {"fr.mycompany.common"})
@EntityScan("fr.mycompany")
@SpringBootApplication(exclude = {DataSourceAutoConfiguration.class})
@EnableConfigurationProperties
public class Application {
```

I precise that the "fr.company.common" is in another subproject with own entities & repositories

My DatabaseConfig class:

```
@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
@EnableR2dbcRepositories(basePackages = "fr.mycompany.activite.ingester.database.repos")
@Slf4j
public class DatabaseConfig extends AbstractR2dbcConfiguration {

    @Value("${spring.r2dbc.host}")
    private String host;
    @Value("${spring.r2dbc.username}")
    private String username;
    @Value("${spring.r2dbc.password}")
    private String password;
    @Value("${spring.r2dbc.database}")
    private String database;

    @Override
    public ConnectionFactory connectionFactory() {
        log.info("Init rd2dbc with host: {}", host);
        log.info("Init rd2dbc with database: {}", database);
        log.info("Init rd2dbc with username: {}", username);
        log.info("Init rd2dbc with password: {}", password);
        return new PostgresqlConnectionFactory(PostgresqlConnectionConfiguration.builder()
                .username(username)
                .password(password)
                .host(host)
                .database(database)
                .build());
    }

    @Bean
    ReactiveTransactionManager transactionManager(ConnectionFactory connectionFactory) {
        return new R2dbcTransactionManager(connectionFactory);
    }

    @Bean
    public ConnectionFactoryInitializer initializer(ConnectionFactory connectionFactory) {
        ConnectionFactoryInitializer initializer = new ConnectionFactoryInitializer();
        initializer.setConnectionFactory(connectionFactory);
        CompositeDatabasePopulator populator = new CompositeDatabasePopulator();
        populator.addPopulators(new ResourceDatabasePopulator(new ClassPathResource("schema.sql")));
        populator.addPopulators(new ResourceDatabasePopulator(new ClassPathResource("data.sql")));
        initializer.setDatabasePopulator(populator);
        return initializer;
    }
```

My repository:

```
public interface OrdreDeTravailPivotV2SplittedRepository extends ReactiveCrudRepository<OrdreDeTravailPivotV2SplittedEntity, OrdreDeTravailPivotV2IdEntity> {

    @Query(value = "SELECT * FROM splitted.ordredetravail WHERE idot = :idOt ORDER BY datemajstatut DESC LIMIT 1", nativeQuery = true)
    Optional<OrdreDeTravailPivotV2SplittedEntity> findLastByItOt(String idOt);
}
```

my entity:

```
@Entity
@Getter
@Setter
@IdClass(OrdreDeTravailIdEntity.class)
@Table(name = "ordredetravail", schema = "splitted")
@TypeDef(
        name = "jsonb",
        typeClass = JsonBinaryType.class
)
public class OrdreDeTravailSplittedEntity implements ISplittedEntity {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "idot")
    private String  idOt;
    @Id
    @Column(name = "datemajstatut")
    private Instant dateMajStatut;
```

Finally my business class which uses my repository:

```
@Slf4j
@Component
public class OrdreDeTravailConverter implements IModelConverter<OrdreDeTravailRawEntity, OrdreDeTravailSplittedEntity, OrdreDeTravailComputedEntity, OrdreDeTravailInputConversionModel> {

    private final OrdreDeTravailSplittedRepository ordreDeTravailSplittedRepository;
    private final OrdreDeTravailComputedRepository   ordreDeTravailComputedRepository;

    @Autowired
    public OrdreDeTravailConverter(OrdreDeTravailSplittedRepository ordreDeTravailSplittedRepository, OrdreDeTravailComputedRepository ordreDeTravailComputedRepository) {
        this.ordreDeTravailSplittedRepository = ordreDeTravailSplittedRepository;
        this.ordreDeTravailComputedRepository = ordreDeTravailComputedRepository;
    }
```

and when I try to launch the application I get the following error:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'fr.mycompany.activite.demande.orion.ingester.database.repos.splitted.OrdreDeTravailPivotV2SplittedRepository' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {}
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.raiseNoMatchingBeanFound(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1790)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1346)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1300)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:887)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:791)
... 85 more
```

do you have an idea ?

Best regards
Adrien

Answer (score 1):

Maybe because you include multiple implementations of RepositoryFactorySupport. You need to let AnnotationRepositoryConfigurationSource#hasExplicitFilters function return true.In spring boot 2.4.2 you must use @EnableR2dbcRepositories and Must have "includeFilters" or "excludeFilters "
My solution(kotlin):

```
//Custom annotations
//Used on the Repository interface
@Target(AnnotationTarget.CLASS)
@kotlin.annotation.Retention(AnnotationRetention.RUNTIME)
@MustBeDocumented
annotation class R2dbcRepository()
//Use above the configuration class
@EnableR2dbcRepositories(includeFilters = [ComponentScan.Filter(type = FilterType.ANNOTATION, classes = [R2dbcRepository::class])])
```